# Best tool to do load testing of wicket framework?

Tags: java, wicket, load-testing

Can you recommend a simple/best tool for an web application developed using Wicket framework?

The challenge is interface id is changed every time so record and playback may not work. This [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-and-jmeter-with-regular-expressions.html) explains some work around but it is not simple to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) you can try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to test web applications. If you use Selenium you show also check [Selenium Inspector](http://seleniuminspector.org/) which is build on top of it and provides convenient assertion methods.

Online service [BrowserMob](http://browsermob.com) offers cloud based load testing based on selenium.

Answer (score 3):

Because the web framework like wicket is on the server side but the load testing tool operates on the client side almost any load testing tools should do the job.

What may be worth a look, depending on your needs:

[Apache AB](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) - The 1st generation load testing tool. It just requests defined urls. However, it's very fast you can easily create a high load from a regular computer. It's a console application

[JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) - One of the first script load testing tools. You can program a test via clicks from some basic actions/validations using a swing interface. Or you can use the proxy recorder to save some amount of work.
But, to be honest, the tool doesn't satisfy me anymore these days.

[The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) - A nice tool - you program the test case via python (in fact jython). This makes complex testing scenarios easily possible. This should defnitly work with wicket, but this tool is also getting old.

[Deja Click](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/3262/) - A firefox plugin which allows recording and replaying web actions. Intentionally not written for web tests and load tests, but it may be worth a look

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) - The 3rd generation of web load testing tools with a big community behind it. You record and edit your test cases via a firefox plugin. Because of the browser integration, more complex tests cases can be recorded in a shorter period of time. 
You should really have a look at this, but keep in mind that Selenium is a acceptance testing tool, and not designed for load testing, but you can do it, if your hardware allows ist. However, you might be in troubles recording the tests if your application does not run in firefox.

[LoadRunner](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-126-17_4000_100__) - A commercial and well-known load testing tool by HP. Haven't tried this yet.

[WebLOAD](http://www.radview.com/product/Product.aspx) - Another commercial alternative.

Comment: The answer is too generic, doesn't address wicket framework specific concern of changing the interface id.

Comment: You can do it with all of the mentioned tools except Apache AB.
I used The grinder for many load tests, and it will perfectly work with changing ids.
(Next time I will spend less time for answering your questions and just mention the grinder to make you happy)

Answer (score 1):

None of the above-mentioned is good at first sight, speaking from experience.

Depending on the complexity of your app, you may need different tools than the ones enlisted and there's no straightforward answer.

If you want an easily recorded and correlated scripts - TruClient by LoadRunner - expensive solution.

Next comes Selenium , but it is generally hard to do any load testing with it, unless you have enormous hardware resources, or your app doesn't require the 100% of the client (load generating machine's CPU or other resource) unless you want to invalidate your test.

Wicket is very dynamic and although it may seem like easy tool for developers, it's kind of hard to be properly tested.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is the tool you are looking for if you don't want to sacrifice your firstborn to get a license.

JMeter provides a proxy you can use to record everything you do. 
The record HTTP-Actions can then be tinkered with and played back.
In most cases you will be able to avoid building Wicket-URLs on your own.
In all other cases it's quite obvious what you have to do (increment a counter ...)

Additionally you get everything you need to generate useful statistics.